# Can I apply an old texture paint file to a new object?

Tags: texture-painting

When I already finish making the icing of my donut, I want to texture painting my donut. For speeding up the process, I open my old texture paint file and apply it to my donut, but the end result looks like this:

[image]

The one below donut picture (first donut picture) is my old texture paint file, and the end result I want is this:

[image]

When I first make the old texture file, I paint it in texture paint mode, not in the UV/image editor. I can't apply a texture paint file to my object, because I paint it in texture paint mode, not in the [UV/image editor](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36265/meaning-of-uv-in-uv-image-editor). How can I apply it to be like the second picture? How can I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it does not matter how you created the image. What matters is how it’s mapped to the 3D object, I.E. the object’s UV map. The maps of the two doughnuts are not the same,  so the texture is getting mapped onto the new doughnut in the wrong way. If you make the UV map of the new doughnut synonymous with the old doughnut’s UV map, that would fix it. However, the map looks kind of auto-generated and arbitrary for the new doughnut, and I’m guessing the same goes for the old, so intentionally reproducing it may be difficult. If the old doughnut’s UV map is too arbitrary to reproduce, I recommend you just start from scratch and unwrap the new doughnut manually before repainting it.

If you are desperate to preserve the old texture, though, you might be able to bake it from one UV map to another, but that is beyond the scope of my knowledge at this point.

Comment: oh ok, thank you, at least now i know that i can't just texture painting my object using my old texture paint file

Comment: You can transfer the UV map from the first object to the next object, or at least try: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/scene_layout/object/editing/link_transfer/copy_uvmaps.html

Comment: @josephhansen I doubt that topology will match, but if it does, that would work.

Answer (score -1):

I guess.

- In your texture, it looks the same as the donut in the first picture. You don't have any texture information which looks like the second picture, so you lost some data, i.e., roughness, normal and so on.
- So the solution is find your old profile, look into [BSDF](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/785/what-is-a-bsdf), and copy those data to your new BSDF. If it works, the way to fix your problem is to bake a series of textures.

Comment: I have copied the bsdf same as the old one but the result is just like you see in the 1st picture, i wonder if i want to transfer my uv map from one object to another, but the object not having same shape and texture.Is that possible?

Comment: Must the shape of them be exactly the same?

Comment: BSDF what? BSDF settings? BSDF parameters? Something else?

Comment: This is incorrect- without duplicate UV mapping, this solution will not work

Comment: @josephhansen BSDF node, i have copied it exact same way as the old one, but the end result is just like in the first picture

Comment: @josephhansen i learned that by using data transfer modifier, i can transfer my old object's uv map to the new object, but when i tried to transfer using it, the uv map didn't transferred at all, my new object's uv map still blank

Comment: The Data Transfer Modifier is not how you copy UV maps, the Blender documentation has some advice and there's some tutorials out there. Google "blender copy uv maps between objects"